# how to get request path in rails3

Tags: heroku, request, ruby-on-rails-3, pdfkit

I am trying to do something similar that I saw in a code snippet for a project in rails prior to 3.0.

The code snippet was in `environment.rb`

```
  config.after_initialize do
    ActionController::Base.asset_host = Proc.new do |source, request|
      if request.format == 'pdf'
        "file://#{Rails.root.join('public')}"
      end
    end
```

how can I incorporate this code in rails ?
which file should it go in?
how do I gain access to the request path?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this for for the public folder. All files and folders in this directory can be accessed from anywhere.